# mesos marathon destory but docker container exist centos7.1.1503

Tags: containers, centos7, mesos, marathon

mesosphere-zookeeper-3.4.6-0.1.20141204175332.centos7.x86_64
mesos-1.0.1-2.0.93.centos701406.x86_64
marathon-1.3.4-1.0.536.el7.x86_64
docker version 1.11.2

I deploy nginx and then destroy it ,but the containter exit and the containter isn't destroyed. I want to know how to delete the containter after I destroy it.

Comment: I look forward to the reploy, please instruct me. Thanks versy much

Comment: Are you saying that the container was left running after the Mesos agent thought that it had been destroyed? What precisely do you notice that leads you to believe the container isn't destroyed? Providing specific log excerpts from the Mesos master/agent or Marathon would be helpful. What kind of Mesos setup are you using?